# html css list with 'p' tag issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

We have lots of List (li tag) directly followed by 'p' tag.

```
<ul>
<li>
   <p>in paragraph</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

in IE8 it is was not a problem. The list image and the text was aligned. But in IE10 text and list icon is not aligned (aligned in compatibility view).

Removing such 'p' tags is a solution but we have it in many places so it is not possible.

How do I solve it?

will really appreciate.

**I notied that it is because of the 'a' tag after 'li' tag. But I cannot remove it. html pages are automatically generated.**

CSS:

```
html{color:#000;background:#FFF;}
body,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,img{border:0;}
address,caption,cite,code,em,th{font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;}
caption,th{text-align:center;}
h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}
q:before,q:after{content:'';}
abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal;}
sup{vertical-align:text-top;}
sub{vertical-align:text-bottom;}
legend{color:#000;}
/* fonts */
select,input,button,textarea{font:99% arial,helvetica,clean,sans-serif;}
table{font-size:inherit;font:100%;}
pre,code,kbd,samp,tt{font-family:monospace;*font-size:108%;line-height:100%;}

 html {background-color: white; 
 scrollbar-shadow-color: white;
scrollbar-highlight-color: white;
scrollbar-face-color: white;
scrollbar-3dlight-color: white;
scrollbar-darkshadow-color: white;
scrollbar-track-color: white;
scrollbar-arrow-color: white;}
Scrollbar hiding*/
   body { font-family: arial;}
  .familylinks {font-family: arial; padding-top:1.75em;} 
  .tablenoborder { margin: 0.5em;}
  .tablecustom{margin-left:-0.4em;}

  .p ol{margin-top: 0em;}


  ul.simple { list-style-type: none }
  ul { list-style-type: disc; list-style-position: outside; padding-bottom: 0.02em; margin-top:-0.05em;}/*--padding-bottom:0.15 changed to 0.05*/

  ol li { margin-left: -1.05em; padding-bottom: 0.25em;}
  ol li p{margin-top:-0.00005em;}
  li p{margin-top:-0.00005em;padding-top:0em;color:red}
  ol.customlists { margin-top: -0.5em}
  ol.customlists { margin-top: -0.25em}
  ol.h2custom{margin-top: 0.5em}
  ol.olcustom{margin-left:2.6em;}
  ul.ulcustom{margin-left:2.6em}

/* Various basic phrase styles */
  .bold { font-weight: bold; }
  .boldItalic { font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; }
  .italic { font-style: italic; }
  .underlined { text-decoration: underline; }


/* Align images based on @align on topic/image */
  div.imageleft { text-align: left }
  div.imagecenter { text-align: center; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em; }
  div.imageright { text-align: right }
  div.imagejustify { text-align: justify }
```

html file example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html lang="en-us" xml:lang="en-us">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css"/>
        <title>Numbering &amp; Bullets</title>
        </head>
        <body>
  <h1>Numbering &amp; Bullets</h1>
  <div>
     <div class="p"><strong>Bullets Test</strong>.</div>

     <ul>
        <li><a><!-- --></a>
          <div><p>in paragraph</p></div>
        </li>
        <li><a><!-- --></a>blha blha blha
        </li>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

regards,
rnv

Comment: Can you post your CSS and (ideally) a sample jsfiddle.net of only a relevant part of code?

Comment: If you want people to help please make the effort to provide the css, maybe screenshots, but even better this is the kind of thing that you could have made a demo for in 2mins

Comment: With Browser specific css problems like these you can try targeting IE10 only -- http://css-tricks.com/ie-10-specific-styles/

Comment: added css and html code

Comment: There's at least one error in your css: missing `/*` before `Scrollbar hiding`. This causes the style for `body` to go unnoticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the `div`, which is a block, so it wants to start on a new line after the inline `a`, even if the `a` is empty (and would have been ignored by older versions).

Solution: turn the `div` into an inline block, so that it sits in the same line as the `a`, to the right of it. In other words, add this to your CSS:

```css
ul a + div {display:inline-block}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/6RPsN/

Edit: or if some of your `a` elements do have content and do need to sit on a line of their own above the div that follows, add `:empty` to the CSS, so that it works only on `a`s without content.

```css
ul a:empty + div {display:inline-block}
```

I'm not sure if this works in the versions of IE that it should work in though; can't test all of them here.

Comment: If there are multiple 'p' tag then the list icon appears at the bottom if I use div is used as inline block. How do I resolve it?

`<li><a><!-- --></a>
<div><p>paragrddahp2</p> <p>paragrahp3</p>
</div>
</li>`

Comment: How do you _want_ to resolve it? By putting the bullets in the middle? That can be achieved by applying `vertical-align:middle` to the `div` in the `li`. [See new Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/6RPsN/1/). The margins in the paragraphs cause minor anomalies in that case (i.e. the bullets are slightly lower than they need to be), but that can be resolved by changing the margins to paddings. [Newer fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/6RPsN/2/). Or if you want to have the bullets on top, just use `vertical-align:top` for the divs. [Even newer fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/6RPsN/3/).

Comment: `<li><a><!-- --></a>normal-text <div><p>paragrddahp2</p> <p>paragrahp3</p> </div> </li>`

Comment: In above example there is no text 'normal-text' and text in the first p tag appear inline. how can we handle such situation?

Comment: Has the situation changed? Has the routine that generates the HTML been updated to output more complicated combinations of code? If so, this should be really a new question. Anyway, I can only repeat what I said in July: what do you want to happen? what should the output be in those situations? Please provide a (fake) screenshot or something that shows how the output should look.

Comment: Situation has not changed. I forgot to take into consideration the fact that someone can specify text without p tag right after div tag followed by p tag.
`<li><a><!-- --></a>normal-text <div><p>paragraph2</p> <p>paragrahp3</p> </div> </li>`
if specified as above 'paragraph2' should appear below the text 'normal-text'.
currently it is displayed inline.
with the following css entry the first p tag is always appears inline
`ul a + div {display:inline-block; vertical-align:top}`